# Hover Effect with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, dom-events

I need some help with JavaScript code. I am trying to get node name from XML data, which I am successful to do so, but now I am trying to create a small `div` which will create so the description box which will show me the name of that element, when I hover over that element. I mean that when I hover on *book*, the description box will show *book*, if I hover over *price*, description box will show *price*. If the mouse cursor go outside that element, then the description tag will vanish, I am attaching the live fiddle. All these things needs to be done with JavaScript, not JQUERY.

[Live Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aliparvez20/DuKkh/8/)

---

```
book
  title
  author
  year
  price
```

---

```js
function moveDescrip(event)
{
    var d = document.getElementsByClassName("Desc")[0];
    var x=event.clientX;
    var y=event.clientY;
    d.style.top = (y + 10) + "px";
    d.style.left = (x + 10) + "px";
}

function showDescrip()
{
    var d = document.getElementsByClassName("Desc")[0];
    d.style.visibility="visible";
}

function hideDescrip()
{
    var d = document.getElementsByClassName("Desc")[0];
    d.style.visibility="hidden";
}
```

Comment: FYI, you can use `title` attribute for tooltip.

Comment: Sir i confused. you mean this.getAttribute('title'), can you please update the live fiddle and show me how to do it?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it is html.. but when I checked fiddle I realized that you are working with XML. I am not sure whether still you can have `title` attribute or not.

Comment: Hey here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/DuKkh/9/).

Comment: This is great but what should i do if i want to put an image inside that description Box??

Comment: I mean putting multiple things inside it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DuKkh/11/) and now it works.

Basically, when you create the 'li' element, I add _name property to it with the node.name value. This way, in the showDescrip event handler, I just have to retrieve the property and put it into the floating div. I'm doing it with innerText. If you'd want to show a more beautiful floating div, with images and so on, you'll have to replace the .innerText = 'desc' with something else, perhaps putting a 'span' element inside the div and placing the description inside it.

Finally, you need to call stopPropagation(), so only the element over wich you are hovering shows the description. If you don't do this, you'll only see the description of the root node.

```
function showDescrip(e)
{
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    var d = document.getElementsByClassName("Desc")[0];
    var descSpan = document.getElementById('float-description');
    var text = document.createTextNode(this._name);
    descSpan.removeChild(descSpan.firstChild);
    descSpan.appendChild(text);
    d.style.visibility="visible";
    e.stopPropagation();
 }

...

function traverse(node) {
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
if (typeof node !== 'undefined') {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li._name = node.name;
    var desc = document.createTextNode(node.name);
    //more code...
```

**EDITED** New [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DuKkh/13/) with what I told you about spans.

Comment: But if i take mouse cursor outside the elements it description box should vanish which is not happening

Comment: Id does. If you move the cursor towards the left border of the div, it eventually disappears. But towards the right, li elements are blocks, so they take the entire width of their container by default. If you want to avoid this, put the node.names inside a *span* tag and attach the mouse events to that element.

Comment: What changes have you done, as when i try your code it dosent work.

Comment: Have you tried the latest version? http://jsfiddle.net/DuKkh/12/. It does work for me. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Sir, the id.innerText = this._name;  dont seem to work

Comment: Yes, I know. I forgot Firefox doesn't support it. Try now: http://jsfiddle.net/DuKkh/13/. And please, don't call me 'sir', it makes me feel old, which I'm not :-)

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure its like that you can do it like that

```
<body>
<div id="mydiv">
<p id="p1" title="" onclick="myfunction()">p one</p>
<p id="p2" title="">p two</p>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunction() {

    var first = "my first p";
    var second = "my second p";
    document.getElementById("p1").title = first;
    document.getElementById("p2").title = second;
}
```

you can generete those from javascript